# MPI execution not as expectation

Tags: python, mpi, mpi4py

I am doing the project on Raspberry Pi 400 with Raspberry Pi OS 64-bit version. I have install the mpich using `sudo apt install mpich`, and I also installed mpi4py using pip. When I run the test program with the following code:

```
from mpi4py import MPI

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
size = comm.Get_size()
rank = comm.Get_rank()

if rank == 0:
   data = [(x+1)**x for x in range(size)]
   print('we will be scattering:',data)
else:
   data = None
   
data = comm.scatter(data, root=0)
print('rank',rank,'has data:',data)
```

I run it with `mpiexec -n 3 python test.py` but it results as following:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/FYP $ mpiexec -n 3 python test.py 
we will be scattering: [1]
rank 0 has data: 1
we will be scattering: [1]
rank 0 has data: 1
we will be scattering: [1]
rank 0 has data: 1
```

I expected that the mpiexec will be run with different ranks recieve the data from rank 0. What happen to the setting of the MPI?

Comment: that typically occurs when `mpiexec` and `libmpi.so` are from different vendors (for example, `mpiexec` is from `MPICH` and `mpi4py` was built on top of `Open MPI`

Comment: Then are there any suggestions on the installations guide on the mpi4py?

Comment: try uninstalling `mpich` and install `openmpi-bin` instead.

Comment: in my environment, `mpi4py` provides a `MPI.cpython-311-darwin.so` file. try looking for such a `.so` file and run `nm` on it. If you see some undefined `ompi_*` symbols, then `mpi4py` was built on top of Open MPI